# glReadPixels GL_RGBA returning ARGB pixels instead

Tags: android, pixel, rgba, glreadpixels, argb

In NDK, Android.
Calling the next instruction to get the viewport pixels. I am expecting the pixels to be in RGBA format, but instead I get ARGB pixels. Is there something wrong or the be set prior to glReadPixels??

```
void getViewPortPixels(const unsigned int x, const unsigned int y, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height, unsigned int* output)
{
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glReadPixels(x, y, width, height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (void*)output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be, does the framebuffer you read is default? Otherwise the color components are read from the color image that attached to the GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 attachment point.
BTW, what's the GPU vendor of your device?